# How to unify two records with same field?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that get records like below:

`SELECT cod, name, doc1, cpf`, the result is:

`cod | name  | doc1 | cpf
   1 | john  |   12 |   0
   1 | john  |    0 | 123
   2 | mary  |   25 |   0
   2 | mary  |    0 | 456
   3 | andy  |   48 |   0
   3 | andy  |   55 | 789`

How to unify the registers with some `cod` like the result below?

`cod | name | doc1 | doc2 | cpf
   1 | john |   12 |    0 | 123
   2 | mary |   25 |    0 | 456
   3 | andy |   48 |   55 | 789`

Comment: Are there only 2 doctors for each cod value? Or do you need a dynamic number of columns too?

Comment: @JacobH only two. but is possible to create a dynamic number?

Comment: How are the two records for a `cod` identified? Is there something that can tell which record goes first?

Comment: @CL. yes, exists a field named date_row. is a integer

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY to get one output row per `cod`, and use aggregate functions to select one value to output. For the doc values, use CASE to select only one of them (it returns NULL in a row where it does not match):

```
SELECT cod,
       name,
       max(CASE date_row WHEN 1 THEN doc1 END) AS doc1,
       max(CASE date_row WHEN 2 THEN doc1 END) AS doc2,
       max(cpf) AS cpf
FROM my_table
GROUP BY cod,
         name
ORDER BY cod;
```